# Disjunction Elimination Proof

Tags: propositional-calculus

P∨(Q∨R) ⊢ Q∨(P∨R)

Proof:

1.) P∨(Q∨R) Assumption

2.) P        Assumption

3.) P∨R     2.) Disjunction Introduction

4.) Q∨(P∨R) 3.) Disjunction Introduction

5.) Q∨R  Assumption

6.) Q     Assumption

7.) Q∨(P∨R) 6.) Disjunction Introduction

8.) R Assumption

9.) P∨R .8) Disjunction Introduction

10.) Q∨(P∨R) .9) Disjunction Introduction

11.) Q∨(P∨R) 5.), 6.), 7.), 8.), 10.) Disjunction Elimination

12.) Q∨(P∨R) 1.), 2.), 4.), 5.), 11.) Disjunction Elimination

I'm having a hard time understanding this proof. Why is it necessary to state line 5? Why is line 11 stated again in line 12?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having a hard time understanding this proof. Why is it necessary to state line 5?

If you have $A\vee B$ and wish to show it proves $C$ -- that is $A\vee B\vdash C$ -- then you may use Disjunctive Elimination.

Disjunctive Elimination is the rule that:

$$A\vee B, A\to C, B\to C \vdash C$$

So Lines 2 and 5 are where you take(assume) two halves of the disjunction $P \;\vee\; (Q\vee R)$ and aim to show that they prove the same thing.   If you *can do* that you have:

$$\overbrace{\underbrace{P\vee (Q\vee R)}_\text{line 1.)}, \underbrace{P\to Q\vee(P\vee R)}_\text{Line 2.), 3.), 4.)}, \underbrace{(Q\vee R)\to Q\vee(P\vee R)}_\text{Line 5), 11.)} \vdash Q\vee(P\vee R)}^\text{Line 12.)}$$

> Why is line 11 stated again in line 12?

Because you use Disjunctive Elimination to conclude line 11 from the assumption of $Q\vee R$.

Does this indentation help?

$\require{cancel}\begin{array}{l|l}
 1.) & P∨(Q∨R) \qquad\cancelto{\text{Premise}}{\text{Assumption }}
 \\
 & \begin{array}{l|l}
  2.) & P \qquad\text{Assumption}
  \\ 
  3.) & P∨R \qquad 2.)\text{ Disjunction Introduction}
  \\\hline
  4.) & Q∨(P∨R) \qquad 3.)\text{ Disjunction Introduction}
 \end{array}
 \\ & \begin{array}{l|l}
  5.) & Q∨R \qquad\text{Assumption }
  \\ & \begin{array}{l|l}
   6.) & Q \qquad\text{Assumption}
   \\ \hline
   7.) & Q∨(P∨R) \qquad 6.)\text{ Disjunction Introduction}
  \end{array} 
  \\ & \begin{array}{l|l}
   8.) & R \qquad\text{Assumption}
   \\
   9.) & P∨R \qquad 8)\text{ Disjunction Introduction}
   \\ \hline
   10.) & Q∨(P∨R) \qquad 9)\text{ Disjunction Introduction}
  \end{array}
  \\ \hline
  11.) & Q∨(P∨R) \qquad\text{5.), 6.), 7.), 8.), 10.) Disjunction Elimination} 
 \end{array}
 \\ \hline
 12.) & Q∨(P∨R) \qquad\text{1.), 2.), 4.), 5.), 11.) Disjunction Elimination} 
\end{array}$

---

$$
\dfrac{
 (1): P\vee (Q\vee R)
}{
 \dfrac{
  \dfrac{
   \dfrac{
    (2): P
   }{
    (3):P\vee R
   }{\small\text{DI}}
  }{
   (4): Q\vee (P\vee R)
  }{\small\text{DI}}
  \quad,\quad 
  \dfrac{
   \dfrac{
    (5):(Q\vee R)
   }{
    \dfrac{
     (6):Q
    }{
     (7):Q\vee(P\vee R)
    }{\small\text{DI}}
    \quad,\quad
    \dfrac{
     \dfrac{
      (8):R
     }{
      (9):P\vee R
     }{\small\text{DI}}
    }{
     (10):Q\vee(P\vee R)
    }{\small\text{DI}}
   }
  }{
   (11):Q\vee(P\vee R)
  }{\small\text{DE}}
 }{
  (12):Q\vee (P\vee R)
 }{\small\text{DE}}
}
$$

Comment: The indentations helped greatly, thanks!